# Changing Datagridview Backgroung color using combobox C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want to change the background color of the Datagridview using another form combobox.

1st form contain datagridview and 2nd form contain some combobox.

**Form 1 datagridview**

[image]

**Form 2 combobox with color dialog box**

[image]

**combobox get the color in color dialog box**

[image]

Query for that

form 1:

```
String MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                "DATABASE=test;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=testing;" + "Convert Zero Datetime = True";

     MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from filter_data", con);
                con.Open();
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dataTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

form 2:

```
private void cmbcolorbg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
            if (cd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                cmbwvcolorbg.BackColor = cd.Color;
            }
        }
```

I dont know how to add an bg color to one form to another form Could anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can get background of Form 2 this way:

```
using (var form = new Form2())
        {
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // you should set DialogResult = DialogResult.OK on Form2 after clicking OK button
            {
                this.BackColor = form.BackColor;
            }
        }
```